# NGINX serves 200 status code in browser for error pages

Tags: nginx, http-status-codes, proxypass

I am using the proxy_intercept_errors on directive. My downstream application is returning 404 and the 404 error page is displayed to the user in the browser, however the actual status code is 200. Has anyone else experienced this behaviour?

Comment: Could you provide your config or at least the relevant section of it?

Comment: I followed the instructions here: http://muratknecht.de/tech/how-to-fix-nginx-soft-404-when-a-404-error-page-returns-200/ removing the = sign from the error_page directive. For example:

`error_page 400 /HTTP_BAD_REQUEST.html;`

rather than

`error_page 400 = /HTTP_BAD_REQUEST.html;`

The relevant documentation page is here however I find it misleading:
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#error_page